# Почему я не вижу public class?

Tags: java, grpc

Есть сгенерированный public class. (из библиотеки grpc). Никак не могу его увидеть. Пытаюсь из класса GreetingClient достучатся до DummyServiceGrpc [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытался импорты вручную прописать (и после перезагружал и ребилдил идею - помогает)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это build.gradle

```
    plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'com.google.protobuf' version '0.8.8'
}

group 'org.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'io.grpc:grpc-netty-shaded:1.25.0'
    implementation 'io.grpc:grpc-protobuf:1.25.0'
    implementation 'io.grpc:grpc-stub:1.25.0'

    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}

protobuf {
    protoc {
        artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.10.0"
    }
    plugins {
        grpc {
            artifact = 'io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:1.25.0'
        }
    }
    generateProtoTasks {
        all()*.plugins {
            grpc {}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: надо добавить импорт пакета где лежит сгенеренный класс. Если это не поможет попробуйте перезапустить Idea у нее это бывает.

Comment: Дополнил, вопрос - пытался уже и прописывать вручную и перезагружать и ребилдить. Вроде по уровням все нормально. Может я чего то не знаю про область видимости сгенеренных файлов, или что то просто упускаю из вида)

Comment: При этом валится честная сборка Gradle'ом?

Comment: С импортами - да валится собственно на этих импортах

Comment: Конкретно сам на такую проблему не натыкался возможно потому, что генерирую классы в сорсы. Скинь build.gradle, думаю, что причину проблем надо искать там.

Comment: Дополнил кодом из build.gradle

Comment: Думаю это должно помочь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13334527/how-do-i-set-a-folder-as-a-source-folder-in-eclipse-with-gradle

Comment: насколько я понимаю idea и так понимает что это source папка, но я все равно поробовал, и мне или не помогло или я не так это использовал. Оно у меня просто перенесло source с папки java на 2 ступеньки вверх на папку src

Comment: Не знаю, насколько это "best practice", но у меня классы генерятся прямо в исходники, а не в папку build. И с этим мы живем уже год и не жалуемся.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел ответ, ваши комментарии помогли покапать в нужном напрвлении)

Только может мне кто-то может объяснить почему он не мог увидеть сгенерированные файлы, без этого (для общего развития)?

В build.gradle прописал

```
 sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs 'build/generated/source/proto/main/grpc'
            srcDirs 'build/generated/source/proto/main/java'
        }
    }
}
```